# jQuery - how to handle clickable elements, that haven't loaded yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a toolbar that is injected into a template on click. The toolbar also consists of a dropdown, which gets hidden if the user clicks outside the dropdown. To track a click outside the dropdown, I use "$(document).click(function()..." The problem is that the dropdown does not exist on document.ready , what could be improved?

JS

```
  $(document).click(function(){
      $('.dropdown').hide();
  });

  $('.dropdown_name').click(function(){
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('.dropdown').show();
  });
```

Comment: Do the `.dropdown_name` elements also not exist on document ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a parent element of the element you want to the click *that already exists on the DOM*, then use `.on` on it. Basically what it does is listen for clicks for the descendants, regardless if they're there or not.

```
$('PARENT_ELEMENT_SELECTOR').on('click','DESCENDANT_SELECTOR',function(e){
  //do what you want here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [on method](https://api.jquery.com/on/) on the document like this

```
$(document).on( "click", ".dropdown_name", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.dropdown').show();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
 var dropdown = false;
 $('.dropdown_name').click(function(){

      e.stopPropagation();
      $('.dropdown').show();
      dropdown = true; // dropdown is now visible

      $(document).click(function(){
          if(dropdown == true)
              $('.dropdown').hide();
              dropdown = false; // dropdown is invisible
      });

  });
```

Comment: There's absolutely no good reason to declare an event handler inside another event handler in this case; you'll end up with additional ones every time a `.dropdown_name` element is clicked. This also sounds like an event delegation problem, I don't see how this code would solve that.